# Create parent child nested JSON from index

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, parent-child

I am newb for D3. I am using d3.jd version 3.
I have following type of JSON:

```
[
  {
    "health": "OK",
    "name": "new A",
    "index": "A"
  },
  {
    "health": "SEVERE",
    "name": "new AB",
    "index": "A > B"
  },
  {
    "health": "OK",
    "name": "new ABC",
    "index": "A > B > C"
  },
  {
    "health": "OK",
    "name": "new ADE",
    "index": "A > D > E"
  },
  {
    "health": "SEVERE",
    "name": "new AD",
    "index": "A > D"
  }
]
```

I want to create following parent child nested data from above JSON:

```
[
  {
    "health": "OK",
    "name": "new A",
    "index": "A",
    "children": [
      {
        "health": "SEVERE",
        "name": "new AB",
        "index": "A > B",
        "children": [
          {
            "health": "OK",
            "name": "new ABC",
            "index": "A > B > C"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "health": "SEVERE",
        "name": "new AD",
        "index": "A > D",
        "children": [
          {
            "health": "OK",
            "name": "new ADE",
            "index": "A > D > E"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want create parent child data through index.
So, If index is "A > B" and "A" is parent and "B" is child.

this is just sample data I have no. of large data. So, want to increase performances.

it is possible with d3 or jquery to create nested parent child JSON form array of object?

Comment: `create nested parent child JSON form array of object` :- that is more easy and non-hectic

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. for It I need to add parent id.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "health": "OK",
    "name": "new A",
    "index": "A"
  },
  {
    "health": "SEVERE",
    "name": "new AB",
    "index": "A > B"
  },
  {
    "health": "OK",
    "name": "new ABC",
    "index": "A > B > C"
  },
  {
    "health": "OK",
    "name": "new ADE",
    "index": "A > D > E"
  },
  {
    "health": "SEVERE",
    "name": "new AD",
    "index": "A > D"
  }
]

  function fnGetParentID(index) {
                     var indexArr = index.split(' > ');
                     var parentIndex = '';
                     if(indexArr.length !== 1){
                         parentIndex = index.replace(" > " + indexArr[indexArr.length - 1], '')
                     }
                     return parentIndex;
                 };

 function fnCreateStrunture(f) {
                    return f.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return a.index.length < b.index.length ? 1 : a.index.length == b.index.length ? a.index < b.index ? -1 : 1 : -1;
                    }).reduce(function (p, c, i, a) {
                        c.ParentID = fnGetParentID(c.index);
                        var parent = !!c.ParentID && a.find(function (e) {
                                return e.index === c.ParentID;
                            });
                        !!parent ? !!parent.children && parent.children.push(c) || (parent.children = [c]) : p.push(c);
                        return p;
                    }, []);
                };
                           
var nestedJson = fnCreateStrunture(data);

document.getElementById("nested").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nestedJson, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="nested"></pre>
```